# How to classify a set of rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am trying to solve this SQL exercise. But I do not have any idea how to do it. Do someone have a good idea?

Try it out: https://dbfiddle.uk/fQmZkOaw

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where did you find this question?

Comment: there are always 2 steps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```sql
SELECT workflow
, case when min(status) = max(status) THEN min(status) -- if all status is same, set to status
     when min(case when status = 'Error' then 0 end) = 0 then 'Intederminate' -- if any status is error then intedermined
  else 'Running' end
FROM #ProcessLog
group by workflow
```

mayhaps?

Comment: The code looks great. I did not know that you can use max on a string column like STATUS. I thought you can only use min max on numbers.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty handy for all kind of types. Just gotta watch out for NULLs, since they are ignored by aggregates

Comment: Why you have such good SQL skills?

Comment: After 15 years of working with it, eventually something is bound to stick to one's brain :D