# How to calculate total progress status from a group of statuses?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to retrieve the status for a multi-step process which is stored in a sql server db. Each step is a record in a table.

When a client wants to know the status of that process, I would like to retrieve the statusses for all steps and have my query return a status of

- 'queued' when all steps have status 'queued',
- 'in-progress' when one of the steps has status 'in-progress',
- 'finished' when all of the steps have status 'finished'.

What would this query look like?

I'm not that experienced in Sql yet so I haven't tried anything yet because I wouldn't know where to start and can't really find anything like this problem on Google.

Edit based on comment:
Tables look like:

```sql
Process
- id uniqueidentifier not null pk
- other stuff
```

```sql
Step
- id uniqueidentifier not null pk
- processId uniqueidentifier not null fk with process.id
- status nvarchar(30) not null
```

So some sample data for step would be:

| id | processId | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ed9d1f80-1941-495a-a282-833fddf41174 | 6f940376-27b5-4899-8cf0-beb89877da46 | in-progress |
| 2738a403-7ad4-4396-9b5c-c641bc01f96f | 6f940376-27b5-4899-8cf0-beb89877da46 | queued |
| 4e6a0c8e-49e9-4dc6-adbe-a74f27aff36f | 6f940376-27b5-4899-8cf0-beb89877da46 | queued |

which should result in my query returning:

| processId | status |
| --- | --- |
| 6f940376-27b5-4899-8cf0-beb89877da46 | in-progress |

Comment: In order for people to be able to help we need the details. In short we need to see your table definition, sample data and the desired output for the sample data. Unless that information is provided this question will very likely be closed.

Comment: If you had a table for status you would do yourself a big favor. For starters it would be normalized, but you could also use that table so you can do an aggregate which would make this really easy.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: What if you have a mix of queued and finished, but nothing in progress?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to classify a set of rows in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74436766/how-to-classify-a-set-of-rows-in-sql)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn That's a great edge scenario I hadn't considered! Thanks. Logically this should also mean that the entire process is in-progress, so this would be a special case I would need to add.

Comment: @siggemannen That post is indeed quite close, but I don't think the title is very descriptive. Neither is mine, but it's a hard problem to describe in a single sentence. Maybe anyone has a better suggestion for a title?

Comment: Agree, the "string" thing makes it to be something from character manipulation. How about, "How to calculate total progress status from a group of statuses"

Answer (score 2):

This should work, and might perform better:

```
SELECT processId, status 
FROM (
    select processId, status
       , row_number() over (partition by processid 
                            order by case when status = 'in-progress' then 0
                                          when status = 'queued' then 1 
                                          else 2 end) rn
    from Step
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

But there's a significant unanswered question in the original post about what to do if there's a mix of only `queued` and `finished` items, with nothing listed as `in-progress`. In this answer, I biased towards the earlier `queued` status.

If you could have more status values in the future, I might do this:

```
SELECT processId, status 
FROM (
    select processId, Step.status
       , row_number() over (partition by processid 
                            order by coalesce(map.priority,100)) rn
    from Step
    left join ( values 
      ('in-progress', 0), 
      ('queued', 1), 
      ('finished' 2)
    ) map(status, priority) ON map.status = Step.status
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

This lists the mapping in a more-concise way with less indentation, making it much easier to read and maintain. It also sets you up to easily convert to a status table down the road. The `LEFT JOIN` and `coalesce()` instead of `INNER JOIN` is so the query doesn't completely skip rows if a status is added before the query is updated to know about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check using the following query:

```
DECLARE @pid int = 7; --whatever the ID of this process is.

SELECT 
   CASE 
   WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ProcessSteps WHERE ProcessID = @pid AND Status = 'in-progress') THEN 'in-progress'
   WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ProcessSteps WHERE ProcessID = @pid AND Status = 'finished') THEN 'queued'
   ELSE 'finished'
   END AS ProcessStatus
FROM ProcessSteps
WHERE ProcessID = @pid
```

The query first checks if **any** of the steps are `in-progress`. If there is any, the status of `in-progress` is returned. Next is checks if **all** the steps are finished, and if not returned `queued`, otherwise it returns `finished`.

Comment: Thanks! This works for me. I'm pretty sure that more statusses will be added in the future but I understand the syntax so I will probably be able to work it out.

Comment: This will certainly work but the performance may become an issue on larger tables. Subqueries as a column are going to impact performance significantly.